# Wie sagt man "it's about time"?

Tags: grammar, translation, english-to-german

> It's about time she went home

Mein Versuch ist :

> Es ist Zeit, dass sie nach Hause gegangen ist.

Comment: Ich habe mich über die Vergangenheitsform von _go_ gewundert. Falls sich noch wer wundert: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/35432/its-about-time-she-came-has-come-its-about-time-to-verb http://www.italki.com/question/70885

Comment: Could you elaborate on the meaning of the English sentence? Not everyone here seems to interpret it in the same way.

Comment: Do you mean: "Ugh, it's about time she went home! She didn't shut up  for 4 hours!" or ... "Alright kids, it's late. It's about time your little friend went home." ...?

Comment: So in der Art :)

Answer (score 9):

Die richtige Übersetzung lautet:

> **Es wird Zeit, dass sie nach Hause geht.**

oder

> Es ist an der Zeit, dass sie nach Hause geht.

oder im Konjunktiv:

> Es wäre an der Zeit, dass sie nach Hause geht.

Bei der Vergangenheitsform (*went home*) handelt es sich in diesem Fall um den Konjunktiv (subjunctive).
Der Satz

> It's about time she went home

drückt die *Meinung*, *Empfehlung* oder das *Gefühl* des Sprechers aus.

Eine gute [Erklärung](http://www.italki.com/question/70885), wie Sätze mit *It's about time* gebildet werden, findet man bei italki.com:

> "It's about time" + past verb = subjunctive: This gives the speaker's opinion, feeling, recommendation or wish about the matter. It's NOT a real past time situation.
>   "It's about time she went home." (Could also be said in a mean way.)
>   "It's about time you sold your car."

Answer (score 4):

> It's about time she went home

Wenn ich diese Aussage korrekt interpretiere (und Sprachinformationsressourcen wie [diese Seite](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/about+time) scheinen mir da zuzustimmen), dann bedeutet die obige Aussage *nicht* zwangsläufig, dass sie bereits nach Hause gegangen ist, sondern dass sie nach Hause gehen sollte (bzw. dies bereits früher hätte tun sollen).

Daher ist eine idiomatische Übersetzung meiner Meinung nach:

> Es ist [an der] Zeit für sie, nach Hause zu gehen.

oder

> Es ist [an der] Zeit, dass sie nach Hause geht.

Varianten:

- Alternativ funktioniert statt *Es ist [an der] Zeit* auch *Es wird Zeit*.
- Wenn klar ist, wer gemeint ist, würde ich in der ersten Version *für sie* eher weglassen. (z.B.: *Sie sieht sehr müde aus. Es wird Zeit, nach Hause zu gehen.*)
- Die Person, auf die man sich bezieht, könnte man eventuell auch mit *bei ihr* ausdrücken. (z.B: *Sie sieht sehr müde aus. Bei ihr ist es an der Zeit, nach Hause zu gehen.*)

Answer (score 2):

Meiner Meinung nach ist das *about* in

> It's about time she went home.

oft eine ironische Untertreibung. Im Deutschen könnte man das nachbilden mit

> Jetzt wird's (aber) langsam (mal) Zeit, dass sie nach Hause geht.

Das

> It's about time

bezieht sich im Englischen nicht nur auf (erhoffte) zukünftige, sondern auch auf gerade im letzten Moment oder (bei ironischem Gebrauch) verspätet eintretende. Da würde man im Deutschen eher sagen:

> Es ist jetzt aber auch Zeit geworden.

Answer (score 0):

> Es wurde Zeit, dass sie nach Hause gegangen ist.

oder etwas stärker

> Es wurde *aber auch* Zeit, dass sie nach Hause gegangen ist.

Edit: Diese Antwort ist falsch, da der Subjunktiv im zweiten Halbsatz nicht beachtet wird, siehe andere Antworten für korrekte Übersetzungsvorschläge.

Comment: Ich würde sagen: "Es wurde aber auch Zeit, dass sie nach Hause ging".  Ich kann aber nicht sagen, warum. Mein typisches Muttersprachlerproblem...

Comment: @Iris Präteritum versus Perfekt. Grob gesagt bevorzugt der Süden für alles das Perfekt, der Norden weniger. Gibt bestimmt auch Fragen dazu hier ;)

Comment: @linac Servus und willkommen auf dem Stackexchange der deutschen Sprache. Da du schon 1k Reputation auf Fahrrädern hast, erspare ich mir mal meine Standardhinweise auf Tour und Help Centre und wünsche nur eine gute Zusammenarbeit ;)

Comment: Nach den Antworten von O. R. Mapper und suemi, denke ich, dass diese Antwort falsch ist.

Comment: Nach einem Gespräch mit einem bilinugalen (dt. +engl.) Muttersprachler bin ich bin jetzt definitiv sicher, dass die Antwort falsch ist (-1)

Comment: Ich hatte mich tatsächlich nur auf den vorderen Teil des Satzes gestürzt, und den interessanten hinteren Teil übersehen.

Answer (score 0):

An additional proposal:

> Sie hätte längst nach Hause gehen sollen.

This makes clear, that the opinion of the speaker is reflected.